# log4j not working with GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt-log4j

I am trying to add log4J in my GWT application

I am refering to this http://log4j-gwt.sourceforge.net/

I added

```
<inherits name="org.apache.log4j.Log4j" />
```

in my gwt.xml file

but its giving compile time error

```
org.apache.log4j.Log4j   not resolved.
```

I added the log4j jar as well in my build path (screenshot attached)

I am struggling and googling for hours now but no luck

[image]

Comment: Logging with log4j (prove me wrong) is possible only with gwt server-side code (or you need to use something like log4j-gwt http://log4j-gwt.sourceforge.net or gwt-log https://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/wiki/GettingStarted )

Comment: yes its true , I am using log4j-gwt, its there in the screenshot

Comment: the link u mentioned above : http://log4j-gwt.sourceforge.net/... Its saying that we need to add  org.apache.log4j.Log4j .. in gwt.xml file .. which i am doing , but its not compiling as u see in the screenshot

Comment: In the project structure look for Modules-Dependencies and check the log4j jars there, Also try File->Invalidate caches and restart in your IDEA - it may be an IDE bug

Comment: checked in modules its there, restart/invalidate cache ,No luck ..are all the required jars are there ?do u think  i need any other jars like slf4j or something in my class path as well?

Comment: also , as u see in the screenshot , there are Classes of  log4j at right side.. but no src files..in my project Library..could that be the reason